# Atiyah and Macdonald, Exercise 2.11, alternate solution?

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, modules

I know there are other solutions to this exercise on MSE, but I came up with this one which is different than any of the others I have seen on this site. I am hoping someone can check this, and if it is incorrect, can someone point out where the flaw in my logic is.

**The Question:**

Let $A$ be a nonzero ring and $\phi : A^m \to A^n$ an injective homomorphism. Show that $m \leq n$.

**Claim 1:** Let $f: M \to N$ be an injective $A$-module homomorphism where $M$ and $N$ are $A$-modules. Furthermore, suppose $\mathfrak{a}\subset A$ is an ideal. Then the induced homomorphism $\overline{f}: M/\mathfrak{a}M \to N/\mathfrak{a}N$ is injective.

*Proof:*

We have the commutative diagram.

\begin{array}{clc}
M &\xrightarrow{f} & N \\
\downarrow & &\downarrow\\ 
M/\mathfrak{a}M & \xrightarrow{\overline{f}} &N/\mathfrak{a}N
\end{array}

The kernel of the composite homomorphism $M \xrightarrow{f} N \to N /\mathfrak{a}N$ is $f^{-1}(\mathfrak{a}N) = \mathfrak{a}M$. As the diagram above commutes, the kernel of the composite $M \to M/\mathfrak{a}M \xrightarrow{\overline{f}} N/ \mathfrak{a}N$ is again $\mathfrak{a}M$; however, this implies that $\overline{f}$ is injective as the kernel of the left map is $\mathfrak{a}M$. $$\tag*{$\blacksquare$}$$

**Claim 2:** If $\phi : A^m \to A^n$ is injective, then $m\leq n$.

*Proof:*

Let $M = A^m$, $N = A^n$, $f = \phi$ and $\mathfrak{a} = \mathfrak{m}$ where $\mathfrak{m}$ is any maximal ideal of $A$. Then by the first claim, $\overline{\phi}$ is an injective linear transformation between finite dimensional vector spaces of dimension $m$ and $n$, respectively; hence, $m\leq n$.$$\tag*{$\blacksquare$}$$

Comment: First things first, the ring should be commutative.

Comment: @darijgrinberg it's an exercise from AM, saying that OP should specify commutativity really seems nit-picky

Comment: @SheafKeef: The name of the book is "Introduction to Commutative Algebra," after all.

Comment: @JJC94 Your claim can be stated like this: if $0\to M\to N$ is an exact sequence of $A$-modules, then by tensoring with $A/\mathfrak a$ it remains exact. Well, this is not really a tensor product property as you probably know (or just learned).

Comment: @user26857 Right. It seemed a little fishy at first, but seeing it written as you said makes it more obvious that it isn't true.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Claim 1 is false. Consider $A=\Bbb Z$, $M=N=\Bbb Z$, $f(x)=2x$ and $\mathfrak a=2\Bbb Z$. The induced morphism $\overline f$ is the zero map $\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z\to\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z$. Specifically, the identity $f^{-1}(\mathfrak a N)=\mathfrak a M$ is not true.